# Add a high score to Snake game

Tags: javascript, cloud9

I was trying to set a high score in my Snake game by using localStorage, but I can't get it to work. Could I get some advice?

This is on Cloud9 using Javascript.

```
<div id = "highscore">High Score: 0</div>

var highscore = 0;
var localStorage = localStorage;
localStorage.setItem("highscore", highscore);
var storage = localStorage.getItem("highscore");
highscore.innerHTML = storage;
if (score > highscore) {
    highscore = score;
}
```

I was hoping that the high score would be retained in localStorage, but for some reason it isn't.

Comment: You have to update the value in localStorage any time it changes if you want to retain that change.

Answer (score 1):

set the score to local storage if the score is greater than highscore

```
if (score > highscore) {
   highscore = score;
   localStorage.setItem("highscore", highscore);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a cookie to storage the high score

i.e.

```
var highscore =  parseInt(getCookie("high_score"));

if (score > highscore) {

    document.cookie = "high_score="+ score + ";";

}


  function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
    var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
    for(var i = 0; i <ca.length; i++) {
      var c = ca[i];
      while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
        c = c.substring(1);
      }
      if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
        return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
      }
    }
    return "";
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I solved it:
Your highest score is saved to localstorege and is always updated and loaded into your HTML code from localstorege after the end of the game.

```
var highscore = localStorage.getItem("highscore");
document.getElementById('highscore').innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("highscore");

if (highscore < score) {
    highscore = score
    localStorage.setItem("highscore", highscore);
}
```

Comment: besides the code, it is better also to have an explanation

Comment: Please add proper explanation to your answer as standalone code snippets are not enough to be considered an answer.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, it's already fixed :-)